# Can the 25 jobs limit on Cloud Dataflow be extended?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I am currently evaluating Google Cloud Dataflow. According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/service/dataflow-service-desc), `you may run up to 25 concurrent Dataflow jobs per Cloud Platform project.`.

This seems very low. I could see a lot of value in running 100s of small to medium size jobs, to be able to support parallel deployments, testing, and to modularize pipelines (many small jobs seems like it could be easier to update/upgrade, even though Dataflow has some support for in-place pipeline upgrades).

Can this limit be increased in some way, like many quotas can be on GCP? What are common practices to work around this limitation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can ask to increase the limit for your project. Can you please write to dataflow-feedback@google.com and give your project ID?